# Can't clone from gerrit

Tags: git, ssh, gerrit

We're moving our gerrit installation and have run into a weird issue.

- The web interface works fine.
- SSH access test works fine, `Hi <name>, you have successfully connected over ssh`

But when I try to clone, with `GIT_TRACE=2` it just stops at unpack:

`$ git clone --verbose ssh://<user>@<ip>:29418/REPO && scp -p -P 29418 <user>@<ip>:hooks/commit-msg REPO/.git/hooks/
10:47:50.633961 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git 'clone' '--verbose' 'ssh://<user>@<ip>:29418/REPO'
Cloning into 'REPO'...
10:47:50.645751 run-command.c:334       trace: run_command: 'ssh' '-p' '29418' '<user>@<ip>' 'git-upload-pack '\''/REPO'\'''`

And it doesn't seem to time out. One of them has been running for ~10 minutes now.

Ideas on what/how to troubleshoot this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: oh come on. 5 minutes after I post this of course it magically start working after refusing for 3 hours. leaving the question up for a bit in case it stops....

Answer (score 0):

Can be a network issue , use --depth option to confirm if we are able to clone latest code without complete git history.

```
git clone --depth 1 --verbose ssh://<user>@<ip>:29418/REPO && scp -p -P 29418 <user>@<ip>:hooks/commit-msg REPO/.git/hooks/
```

Tip : with latest git version , you can unpack / get complete code after cloning with --depth as well.